# react-hook-form - how to reset formState.isDirty after form submitting

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

as I wrote in the title, please give me a hint on how to reset `isDirty` field from `formState` object.

In my application, I have a 'save' button which is disabled by default. When I change the value of any input the button is set to enabled because `isDirty` state is changed to true.
After a successful save action, I want to make my save button disabled again (so I need to set `isDirty` as false again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After successful form submission, you can reset form to its original state using `reset` from `useForm` hook. This will reset `formState` and `isDirty` value will be `false`.

Docs: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/reset

Comment: Nice, I don't know why I didn't think about it earlier. Sometimes the simplest way is the best way! Thank you so much.